# Difference Between class parameter declaration in Scala

Tags: scala

can some one help me in understand the below two declarations

```
class Person1(name: String, id: Int) { }
class Person2(val name: String, val id: Int) { }
val p1 = new Person1("personOne", 1)
val p2 = new Person2("personTwo", 2)
println(p1.name) // ERROR
println(p2.name) // OK!!
```

I know that by default the parameters are `val` . Why the first `p1` is able to return data and `p2` could not do the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting formally from the Scala specification:

> The scope of a formal value parameter includes all subsequent parameter sections and the template t. However, a formal value parameter may not form part of the types of any of the parent classes or members of the class template t. It is illegal to define two formal value parameters with the same name.

The parameter sections and the template `t` basically describes the entire class scope.

On the JVM implementation of Scala, when you create a class in Scala and don't specify the `val` keyword, the compiler sets the scope of the field to `private[this]` and doesn't create a matching method for outer visibility. Meaning (thanks @Duelist for the wording) the values are only in scope for the enclosing class (this includes class methods and any lazy fields), nothing more:

```
class Person1 extends scala.AnyRef {
  <paramaccessor> private[this] val name: String = _;
  <paramaccessor> private[this] val id: Int = _;
  def <init>(name: String, id: Int): yuval.tests.Person1 = {
    Person1.super.<init>();
    ()
  };
  <empty>
};
```

When you add the `val` keyword:

```
class Person1 extends scala.AnyRef {
  <paramaccessor> private[this] val name: String = _;
  <stable> <accessor> <paramaccessor> def name: String = Person1.this.name;
  <paramaccessor> private[this] val id: Int = _;
  <stable> <accessor> <paramaccessor> def id: Int = Person1.this.id;
  def <init>(name: String, id: Int): yuval.tests.Person1 = {
    Person1.super.<init>();
    ()
  };
  <empty>
};
```

A `def` is added to the fields which makes them visible outside of the enclosing class, thus visible from at the use site.

Comment: Can't we just say that when we don't specify val/var it means that these variables are local in primary constructor's scope?

Comment: I think that's definitely not a proper way, and "the values are only in scope for the primary constructor" is even less so; they are in scope for all class methods and lazy val initializers which aren't part of the primary constructor.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov You're right, the scope is definitely broader than the primary constructor. Will update.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov This answer describes the implementation, not the language specification.  See https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/8384.html

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Why do you say that class methods aren't part of the primary constructor? They are placed inside the primary constructor in the same way as a local function is placed in an outer function. Therefore the parameters of the outer function (in this case the constructor) are in scope for the local function (in this case the methods).

Comment: @Tim They are placed inside the class template (https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/05-classes-and-objects.html#templates), which the specification distinguishes from the primary constructor.

Comment: @Tim You can actually define a local variable or a local function inside (a block inside) a primary constructor; they won't be members of the class/trait.

Comment: @Tim Be it the implementation and not the specification, do you see anything wrong with the answer that should be corrected?

Comment: @Tim I'm not seeing anything in the spec that contradicts any of the above, not sure what exactly you're referring to.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Your answer is wrong because it describes the formal value parameter as a "field" but it is not a field, it is just a parameter.

Comment: @Tim I've added the formal specification reference which talks about the visibility scope in general. Non the less, showing the concrete implementation for a specific backend (JVM) which lifts the constructor parameter to a private field on the class, IMO, does not make this answer wrong, it just shows more detail for a specific subset of Scala.

Answer (score 3):

A class parameter with a `val` declaration is a `public val` field of the class.

A class parameter without a `val` declaration is just like a parameter to any other function. It is a constant value whose scope is the whole of the declaration. It can "escape" from the class if it is referenced by a function that is accessible outside the class (method or non-method).

**Note**: Contrary to other answers to this question, a class parameter without a `val` is **not a field** of the class, though it may be implemented that way. See https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/8384.html

**Note**: A `case class` is different in that ***all*** parameters to a `case class` are `public val` fields of that class, with or without an explicit `val` before their name.

Comment: Any clue why this is downvoted? If it is wrong, please let me know so that I can learn something

Comment: thanks for your clear explanation. I've just also faced with similar question, and your answer were most helpful for me.